# return a common vector from others

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

[The common starting point & transformation vector between Aa & Bb would be (3,3)[1,2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCl6y.jpg)I have a point A with coordinates (a, b, c) and I am transforming it by vector [d, e, f].

I also have point B with coordinates (g, h, i) which will have a transformation vector of [j, k, l]

I need to find a starting point & transformation vector which is common to both.

Please, even if you cannot give me the actual answer, any pointers in the right direction would be good!

Comment: What do you mean by a transformation vector? Also what do you mean by a starting point and transformation vector common to both points.

Comment: Say A  = starting coord of (2,2) and a transformation vector of [3,3], B = starting coord of (4,4) and TV [3,3]. The starting point [4,4] and a translation vector of [1,1] would lie on both lines.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't make things much clearer to me. By a point with a transformation vector, do you mean you have something like the following: Let $p$ be a point, $v$ be a vector, then consider the line $\{p+tv : t\in\Bbb{R}\}$? And then you have two lines in 3-dimensional space and want to find their intersection? (If it exists, I assume)

Comment: I think that I have added an image to clarify.